# Public variables in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to razor and I am trying out new things. Is there any way, using razor of having a variable in a file which can be accessed by a rendered page without having to pass the variable on?

For instance, if there is a page called index.cshtml which has the code

```
@{var myVal = 9;}

@RenderPage("_page.cshtml")
```

Is there any way of declaring myVal so that it can be accessed by _page.cshtml?
I don't want to pass the variable form the RenderPage function since I will be rendering more pages and don't want to pass the variable individually.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way of declaring myVal so that it can be accessed by _page.cshtml

Yep, you can store it in the `ViewBag` e.g.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.MyVal = 9;
        return Index();
    }
}
```

**_page.cshtml**

```
<p>My val is @ViewBag.MyVal</p>
```

Comment: is this similar to a session variable?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane they are similar with regards to being able to access them directly in the page, however, that's about as far as similarities go between the 2. In terms of lifespan, implementation & usage they are completely different.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane what do you mean? No class has been created, the example is showing how you would set the `ViewBag` property in your controller...